# Why Icon element require Id attribute to end with '.exe' or '.ico'

Tags: wix, icons, windows-installer

**Why Icon for Shortcut element should have Id attribute ending with '.ico' or '.exe'?**

So this code

```
<Icon Id="ProgramIcon" SourceFile="Images\MyAppIcon.ico"/>

<Component Guid="MY_GUID" Id="MyAppComponent">
    <File Source="MyApp.exe" Name="MyApp.exe" Id="MyApp.exe">
        <Shortcut Id="MyApp.Shortcut" Directory="ApplicationProgramMenuDir" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyApp" Icon="ProgramIcon" Advertise="yes" />
    </File>
</Component>
```

generates compile error:

```
error LGHT0204: ICE50: The extension of Icon 'ProgramIcon' for Shortcut 'MyApp.Shortcut' does not match the extension of the Key File for component 'MyAppComponent'. [D:\APPS\MyProject.wixproj]
```

but this code

```
<Icon Id="ProgramIcon.ico" SourceFile="Images\MyAppIcon.ico"/>

<Component Guid="MY_GUID" Id="MyAppComponent">
    <File Source="MyApp.exe" Name="MyApp.exe" Id="MyApp.exe">
        <Shortcut Id="MyApp.Shortcut" Directory="ApplicationProgramMenuDir" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyApp" Icon="ProgramIcon.ico" Advertise="yes" />
    </File>
</Component>
```

compiles fine.

It's first time I see such limitations for Id attribute of any element and it looks very strange. I don't see any reason for this even to be a warning. So I don't understand some basics of this functionality. Please help me understand the reasons of described behavior.

Comment: For viewers: the only difference between snippets is the Icon Id attribute in the first line

Answer (score 6):

Looks like it's because of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369210.aspx (see the remarks section).

I'm guessing it's failing validation because `Icon="ProgramIcon"` does not match the extension of the shortcut.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_shortcut.htm says

> Identifier reference to Icon element. The Icon identifier should have the same extension as the file that it points at. For example, a shortcut to an executable (e.g. "my.exe") should reference an Icon with identifier like "MyIcon.exe"

Comment: Thanks for an answer. But the key question is that i don't understand WHY is this requirement exists. Though you correctly pointed that this is limitation not of WIX, but of MSI

Answer (score 0):

I think I may be able to shed some light on this.

It likely has to do with the fact that id ends up being the name of the file containing the icon. It would hazard a guess that it uses the file extension to determine which parser to use.

**How I stumbled upon this?**

Seemingly unrelated, I am investigating an issue where the Windows Event logs is filled with SxS errors originating from our application. But the path is all wrong:

`C:\Windows\Installer\{Guid}\ProductIcon.exe`

Incidentally, `ProductIcon.exe` this is the icon id we use.

Upon closer inspection, I see that this file is a copy of our product's executable. The reason we  get the SxS errors is that it only copies the executable and none of the referenced dll-s.